# Compare 2 arrays and create a new one based on if exist, swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, compare

I have 2 arrays:

One of them contains a list of reserved words

```
var reservedWords = ["var", "if", "for", "switch", "int", "class"];
```

The next one contains possible variable names (including some "reserved words")

```
var varNames = ["if", "var", "identifier, "thisIsAnIdentifier", "b13", "a", "i", "number_1", "switch", "int", "class"];
```

I want to compare both arrays and create a new one with just those words that are not in "reservedWords". The new array should look like this:

```
var newArray = ["identifier, "thisIsAnIdentifier", "b13", "a", "i", "number_1"]
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried/done

Comment: well, actually I'm trying to do something harder and I just needed to know how to do that comparison 

Comment: Your question came up in Review, so I was just giving some feedback for how to write better questions :)

Comment: hello there, I already asked another question with my real problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908369/how-can-i-remove-the-parenthesis-from-a-regex-result-in-swift-5
hope you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter` to do this:

```
var reservedWords = ["var", "if", "for", "switch", "int", "class"]
var varNames = ["if", "var", "identifier", "thisIsAnIdentifier", "b13", "a", "i", "number_1", "switch", "int", "class"]

let newArray = varNames.filter {!reservedWords.contains($0)}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: thanks! actually it works without backticks, I guess because the reservedWords are between " " and now they're strings
but it works very well anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
let newArray = varNames.filter({!reservedWords.contains($0)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is if [you use Sets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2853353-subtracting), specifically `Set.subtract` (modifies list) or `Set.subtracting` (creates new list). Since Sets are unique, it should perform better.

```
let employees: Set = ["Alicia", "Bethany", "Chris", "Diana", "Eric"]
let neighbors = ["Bethany", "Eric", "Forlani", "Greta"]
let nonNeighbors = employees.subtracting(neighbors)
print(nonNeighbors)
```

> "["Chris", "Diana", "Alicia"]"

Comment:  this looks interesting! the problem is that I need to do a lexical-analyzer for an school project, so I declared my "tokens" as a dictionary, then I create an array with the keys (arrayKeys) and I'm comparing the arrayKeys with the original array to see which words are identifiers and wich are not, am I explained?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58907998/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-parenthesis-in-a-regex-result-swift-5

Comment: @IsraelSantiago Makes sense. I'm guessing you can convert an array to a set easily, but if you're only using it once, it might not help the performance

Comment: well the performance is not a big deal because I'm learning and also this is an school project so I need to approve the class 

Comment: this is a resume of my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908369/how-can-i-remove-the-parenthesis-from-a-regex-result-in-swift-5
thanks!