# How can I remove the parenthesis from a regex result in swift 5?

Tags: arrays, swift, regex

this is my first time with swift and I have some troubles with an school project

I have the following:

```
var tokens = ["if", "for", "(", ")", "while", "var"]
var test = "if, identifier, for, (, ), while, var1, 3var, ResultVariable, i dentifier";
var lineas = [String]()
```

I converted the "test" into "lineas" array:

```
lineas = data.components(separatedBy: ", ")
```

Then I created the following regex pattern to find ids in the "test" string (id is any variable name)

```
//id: any word that begins with lowercase and can have 0 or more alphanumerics characters
let id = "[a-z][\\w]*"
let regexId = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: id, options: [])
```

The result of the regex is saved in a String and then into in array

```
let idString = regexId.stringByReplacingMatches(in: test, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: test.count), withTemplate: "($0)")
let idArray = idString.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

Then I try to compare the "idArray" with the "tokens" array to obtain only the ids

```
let idResults = idArray.filter({!tokens.contains($0)})
print("\nID found\n")
for ids in idResults{
    print(ids)
}
```

But the output I got is:

```
ID found:
["(if)", "(for)", "(identifier)", "(for)", "(while)", "(var1)", "3(var)", "R(esultVariable)", "(i) (dentifier)"]
```

When the output I need is:

```
ID found:
["identifier, var1"]
```

And this is because "3var, ResultVariable, i dentifier" are not identifiers because they start with numer, uppercase or have an space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution not based on regex that instead uses the `filter` function in different ways

```
var tokens = ["if", "for", "(", ")", "while", "var"]
var test = "if, identifier, for, (, ), while, var1, 3var, ResultVariable, i dentifier";
var lineas = test.components(separatedBy: ", ")

let identifiers = lineas
    .filter {!tokens.contains($0)} // Not a token
    .filter {  // Starts with lowercase letter
        guard let first = $0.first else { return false }
        return first.isLetter && first.isLowercase
    }
    .filter { $0.rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespaces) == nil } // No whitespace
```

Of course the above can be merged in to one call of `filter` but I left it as 3 separate calls for clarity.

Comment: awesome! that works perfectly, thank you! I already implemented this on my code
but I'm still having curiosity about regex, why it is not working?